# Multistreaming vs MultiThreading with UDP sockets in C

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing, udp

I'am building a UDP client socket in C and my final goal is to find out the network maximum throughput, let's say is 10Gb/s.

Initially I started with just a simple socket and the throughput was nowhere near those values.

In order, to achieve higher values I have tried to implement multi-threading and multi- processing which have helped me improve those initial values. Someone has mentioned multi-streaming would also be a good technique to test and check the results.

However, I'am not sure what that person meant by multi-streaming or how I would implement it.

Wouldn't multi-streaming be the same as having multiple sockets in different threads and send the packets through them?

Comment: It sounds like you may be testing with sender and receiver running on the same physical machine.  That doesn't tell you much about your network.

Comment: No, not at all. The received and server is another node in my network!

Comment: I am not aware of multistreaming as a specific network-level concept.  The term seems to be coming into use as an application-level description of communicating with multiple services (pseudo-)simultaneously, such as described here: https://streamyard.com/multistreaming. If you want to try something like that then set up multiple remote destinations for your client to send messages to, each on its own machine.  That could involve multiple threads, but it does not necessarily have to do.

Comment: You should also experiment with the size of your message payloads.  The optimum is probably somewhere near either 1500 bytes, 9000 bytes, or 65500 bytes. The first two are near typical MTUs for ethernet networks, and the last is near the maximum payload size that UDP can accommodate.

Comment: I do get a lot of improvement when I increase the size of my packets , specially on 9000 bytes (jumbo frames), but the interface I'am currently sending to has an MTU of 1500 and will discard packets with size above those values.

Comment: It would be worthwhile to know the line rate of your network equipment.  You mention 10 Gb/s, so are all endpoints, routers, and switches connected via 10 Gb network interfaces? Is all cabling between them rated for 10 Gb speed?  Are they all negotiating 10 Gb data rates?  Note in particular that although 10 Gb NICs are becoming more common, they are still relatively rare.  1 Gb NICs are far more common, even on new machines.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct assumption and what I'am trying to do is to find out how to maximize the number of packets I send to my target server (uploading ). Unfortunately the client running this socket is not a particularly powerful machine and the CPU is limited, which I think is what's causing me some issues to obtain the results I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't multi-streaming be the same as having multiple sockets in different threads and send the packets through them?

I take "multi-streaming" to mean communicating with multiple remote endpoints at the same time, especially via streaming applications / protocols, especially sending the same data to each remote peer.  I don't see any reason to *assume* multithreading there, but a multithreaded strategy such as you describe seems a likely approach.